# Android ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor execute delayed task immediately

Tags: java, android

I have a background task that I run using the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with code like this.

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new BackgroundSync(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

BackgroundSync implements Runnable.

Sometimes from a user event I want the delayed event to run now and not when the 15 minute timer goes off.

Some requirements:

- There should only be one "BackgroundSync" running at a time
- Based off an user event I should be able to schedule a BackgroundSync immediately IF its not running already.

Comment: How do you distinguish when to run delayed and when to run now? Based on what?

Comment: To clarify this recurring task is scheduled immediately for every 15 minutes. However if a user clicks a certain button then I need to run the task immediately assuming its not running already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scheduleWithFixedDelay](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) returns a ScheduledFuture. When calling it, store this somewhere and check if it exists if you want to do the immediate execution. Then you can cancel the scheduled future using the [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method and schedule your runnable again for immediate execution.

Answer (score 2):

Kabuko's solution is probably as good as you will get, but there is a snag.

The `cancel()` method returns `true` if the task was cancelled before it started, and `false` if the task has already run, or if it was previously cancelled.  The problem is that if the task is currently running, `cancel()` will return `true`.  Thus you need to implement some other mechanism to decide whether or not to resubmit the task.

Comment: I've read the android java doc I'm wondering exactly how these future objects actually work with recurring tasks. With a normal task it represents the execution of the single thread task. What does it mean in my case though if I cancel am i only cancelling the current run? or the entire recurring task.

Comment: A scheduled task is not a recurring task - it is simply a task that will be run ... once ... on or after a designated future time point.  It is up to you to design your "recurring task" building block, decide what you want `cancel()` to do, and how to implement it.